# Storing and Retrieving only specific rows from gridview into a session and calling it onto another gridview on another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new to asp.net. I am trying to code a shopping cart. So far I was able to display my items in a gridview however I did this through a list with **no datasource**.

My Shop page is suppose to display my Gridview with columns such as ID, Name, Price, and then a template field of Quantity.

I then want to only take the rows that has the textbox quantity filled with some number and display only those rows onto another gridview onto my ShoppingCart page.

Therefore the other items that do not have any input in the quantity textbox should not appear onto the shopping cart page. Here are my code:

**Shop.aspx**

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Price" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuant" runat="server">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer"
                        ControlToValidate="txtQuant" ErrorMessage="Value must be a whole number" ForeColor="Red"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<br />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

**Shop.aspx.cs**

```
    // go through each product row
    foreach (GridViewRow Products in gvProducts.Rows)
    {
        string tb = (gvProducts.FindControl("txtQuant") as TextBox).Text; //get tb value
        if (tb == null) // if textbox is null
        {
        }
        else
        {                       
            List<string> selecteditems = new List<string>();//create a list called addeditems
                        selecteditems.Add(tb);
 string[] addeditems = selecteditems.ToArray();//convert list to array

Session["ShoppingCart"] = addeditems; // save arraylist as session called ShoppingCart
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/ShoppingCart.aspx");
```

**ShoppingCart.aspx**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvProductsList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="Order Total: "></asp:Label>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Keep Shopping" OnClick="btnBack_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="btnDone" runat="server" Text="Done" OnClick="btnDone_Click" />
```

**ShoppingCart.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
    {
        Response.Write("Your Shopping Cart is empty");
    }
    else
    {
       string[] addeditems = (string[])Session["ShoppingCart"];//call the session back
        gvProductsList.DataSource = addeditems;
        gvProductsList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show your code for binding `gvProducts`, how you are binding? Another thing to clear out that you saved only quantity field in `Session["ShoppingCart"]` , so from where it get ID,Name,Price for `gvProductsList` in _ShoppingCart.aspx_ page to bind GridView.

Comment: The code behind for binding gvProducts(get Details is the name of the list in my Products class):
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//bind list to gridview
        {
            gvProducts.DataSource = Products.getDetails();
            gvProducts.DataBind();
        }

Comment: I am a bit confused on how to bind the ID, Name and Price. I have 2 classes, Products and Shopping Cart. In the Products class I have get and set methods for int ID, string Name, and double Price and then the list of products. In the Shopping Cart class I have         public Products Item { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

You do not "bring" rows from a GridView into a "Session".  You analyze which rows of data you need and get the appropriate references from the backing data store.  With those references you build a shopping cart entry with the appropriate item id and quantity.

But you you are also transferring control to another page.  You have to make sure the items selected for the shopping cart are available there.  You cannot pass data to Page2 using a variable created in Page1.  You need to store the data in such away that it's retrievable from Page2.  This is called *persisting the data*.

Ideally you should create a Shopping cart table in a database that is based on your ShoppingCart class plus a user id.

But this can be done using the Application Cache.  Create your Product list and Shopping cart list there, but only once:

```
public partial class Page1 : System.Web.UI.Page {
  List<Products>     Products     = null ;
  List<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCart = null ;

  protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    if ( !Page.IsPostBack ) {
      Cache[ "Products" ] = new List<Products>;
      Cache[ "ShoppingCart" ] = new List<ShoppingCart>;

      Products     = ( List<Products> )     Cache["Products"];
      ShoppingCart = ( List<ShoppingCart> ) Cache["ShoppingCart"];

    }
  }
}
```

Then when you transfer to Page2 the Products and ShoppingCart will be available via the Application Cache:

```
public partial class Page2 : System.Web.UI.Page {

  List<Products>     Products     = null ;
  List<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCart = null ;

  protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    // be sure to check for null
    Products     = ( List<Products> )     Cache["Products"];
    ShoppingCart = ( List<ShoppingCart> ) Cache["ShoppingCart"];
  }
}
```

This also allows you to delete items from the shopping cart and have the updated "Cart" data available when you transfer back to Page1.